# fail2ban console error message

Tags: linux, console, redhat-enterprise-linux

I constantly receiving this message on my console (where I'm currently logged in). I was banned via fail2ban about week ago using 3 time wrong password on scp command. But now I can used it again. I've check jail.conf file but can't figure out what can be wrong..

System: Red Hat Enterprise 6.3 (Santiago)

Fail2Ban version: 0.8.4

Can someone know what can be problem?

```
Message from syslogd@SERVERNAME at Aug 13 17:14:29 ...
�<28>fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]

Message from syslogd@SERVERNAME at Aug 13 17:14:46 ...
�<28>fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
```

Comment: Is that the actual real message with all the `xxx` in it or have you just masked them? Most likely its `warning` about possible intrusion. fail2ban does dump some text to console every now and again; Seeing the date stamp is a few seconds apart. Same IP??

Comment: NO, I've masked IP's, but i've check them and they belong to my machine (WAN). This is one address.

Comment: Well then something your machine is doing is making fail2ban think it needs to be banned. maybe postfix? apache? sometimes if you enable samba login fails it could ban you for that. But this says SSH- sooo... wierd

Comment: Known bug.
https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/32